# Casting Error When Value is 0 Float to Double

Tags: c#, variables, dataset, sqldatatypes

The below bit of C# code is giving me a Casting error whenever the price value is 0.0 in the database. The field type is a float in the database it is reading it from. Does anyone know the problem?

```
double decPrice = (double)dsqry2.Tables[0].Rows[intCountOrders]["Price"];
```

Comment: are you sure that is the actual error? doesn't sound right to me

Comment: I think that `Tables[0].Rows[intCountOrders]["Price"]` could be nullable and is null. The 0.0 you see (where?) might just be what you see if the value is null. So, you might need to check for nullness before castring.

Comment: Are you sure it's `0.0` and not `DBNull.Value`?

Comment: could try `Double.parseDouble(dsqry2.Tables[0].Rows[intCountOrders]["Price"]);`

Comment: Boxed value type cannot be converted to another type than same type or `Nullable<T>` of the type. What you're doing is not a cast. It is Unboxing.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Convert.ToDouble`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.todouble.aspx) instead of casting.

```
double decPrice = Convert.ToDouble(dsqry2.Tables[0].Rows[intCountOrders]["Price"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

My favorite and safest solution to things like this is simple:

```
var x = dsqry2.Tables[0].Rows[intCountOrders]["Price"];
var decPrice = x is double ? (double)x : 0;
```

Comment: @downvoter care to explain? Works perfect whether the value is a double or DBNull.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Show me a test case where this fails. I'm now working with a `DateTime?` column, and `is DateTime` returns true if the value is not `DBNull`, which is when the cast also works.

Comment: Try this object obj = 5f;  var x = obj;  var decPrice = x is double ? (double)x : 0; try this `decPrice` will be 0

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Of course it will, because `float` is not `double`. The actual case is that the object can either contain `double` or `DBNull`. If the data type is not compatible, the issue is different. If the data type is float, just replace every `double` with a `float` in my answer, and it will work. Same goes for `bool`, `DateTime` and what not. You'll need to match data types between the different layers either way. It's logic.

Comment: Pls read question OP has clearly mentioned it is float. **The field type is a float in the database**. how come this solution work then?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel SO REPLACE DOUBLE WITH FLOAT IN MY ANSWER.

Comment: OP wants to caste to DOUBLE not to FLOAT

Comment: @SriramSakthivel The challenge is behind us, brother. `float fRes = ...; double dRes = (double)fRes;`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
dsqry2.Tables[0].Rows[intCountOrders].Field<double>("Price")
```